# Cannot save to databases while press button

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a code of a button from a panel like this :

```
    try{
        Koneksi objKoneksi = new Koneksi();
        Connection kon = objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi();
        Statement stat = kon.createStatement();
        String query = "insert into transaksi(invoiceno,kode,nama,jumlah,harga,total) values('"
                +Invoice.getText()+"','"
                +Kode.getText()+"','"
                +Nama.getText()+"','"
                +Jumlah.getText()+"','"
                +Harga.getText()+"','"
                +Total.getText()+"','";
        int rows = stat.executeUpdate(query);

        if(rows==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data sudah tersimpan");
            kon.close();
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){}
}
```

And also a Connection class :

http://pastebin.com/8vZpw9Ek

and statement class :

http://pastebin.com/VK358WJZ

(Sorry for not post the code here. I had some trouble on preformatted text block)

When i hit the button to save the data to databases, here comes the error :

```
Connection success:
You are not connected to database
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafinalproject.Aplikasi.SaveActionPerformed(Aplikasi.java:184)
at javafinalproject.Aplikasi.access$200(Aplikasi.java:15)
at javafinalproject.Aplikasi$3.actionPerformed(Aplikasi.java:83)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)dd
```

And Many motre

can someone help me with this?
Thanks before

Answer (score 2):

There is an exception occurring here:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("You are not connected to database");
    return null;
}
```

You are suppressing it, you should show it via `ex.printStackTrace()`.
Anyway, the method is then returning `null` which is causing a `NullPointerException` here:

```
Statement stat = kon.createStatement();
// --------------^^^
```

**Update:**

Put it here:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("You are not connected to database");
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

<sub>PS: your best bet would be to go talk with your teacher/professor, it seems that you lack the basic understanding necessary to fix this issue.</sub>

Comment: Check if this is returning null or Connection object objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi(). If it is returning null then you have to debug objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi() this method

Comment: As I said in the answer, once you print your exception, you will be able to see what's wrong. I can't guess...

Comment: Debug this line   Connection kon = objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi(); . Check what is value of kon execution of this line

Comment: where do i have to put the ex.printStackTrace?

Comment: It seems that your code posted here is fine. But that `bukaKoneksi()` call might not be fine. It's expected to give you a database connection, but for some reason the connection is not established. Note that the actual connection may be not done at the `bukaKoneksi()` call time;  it may be postponed by the driver until you issue the first SQL statement.

Comment: give implementation of bukaKoneksi method in class Koneksi

Comment: @epoch it shows at javafinalproject.Koneksi.bukaKoneksi(Koneksi.java:18)

Comment: @AllahbakshAsadullah i don't understand with debug the line. So do with "Implementation". I'm a new student in university. Please help

Comment: ok, so the actual issue is that the driver you specified is not found on the classpath, you need to ensure that it is available on the classpath. anyway see my ps note.

Comment: Yes my professor is such a $^@#^$#. He won't teach basic to students.
So what's the solution?

Comment: then you should find another tutor that would be willing to teach you part time, but this is beyond the scope of SO. good luck

Comment: i'm glad you got it :)